# Integração Latex e Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, latex

Preciso gerar e salvar um arquivo PDF com alguns dados que tratei num script que fiz para gerar relatório, porém, não sei como fazê-lo.

Estes dados necessitam passar por um arquivo .tex antes de gerar o PDF?
Se sim, como posso, trabalhar com variáveis(?) dentro do arquivo .tex? *Por exemplo, modificar o cabeçalho, adicionar dados em colunas (dados de um dataframe) , adicionar imagens contendo gráficos.*

Se não, qual a forma de gerar um arquivo PDF com Python?

OBS.: já tenho um arquivo .tex que foi escrito e configurado por um terceiro, só preciso integrar este arquivo com python.

Comment: Já pensou em utilizar o [`pweave`](http://mpastell.com/pweave/examples/index.html)? Eu utilizo uma ferramenta parecida no `R`, chamada `knitr`, e tenho obtido resultados muito bons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### [Reportlab:](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/reportlab)

Com o reportlab voce pode gerar os pdfs sem a necessidade de gerar um `.tex`, mas se vc conhece latex e a tarefa que vc está fazendo é academica e/ou científica, eu optaria por PyLaTeX.

### [PyLaTeX:](https://github.com/JelteF/PyLaTeX)

"Biblioteca python para criação e compilação de arquivos (ou fragmentos) latex. O objetivo desse pacote é proporcianr uma interface extensivel e de fácil utilizacção entre python e latex."

Exemplo básico (da documentação):

```
from pylatex import Document, Section, Subsection, Command
from pylatex.utils import italic, NoEscape


def fill_document(doc):
    """Add a section, a subsection and some text to the document.

    :param doc: the document
    :type doc: :class:`pylatex.document.Document` instance
    """
    with doc.create(Section('A section')):
        doc.append('Some regular text and some ')
        doc.append(italic('italic text. '))

        with doc.create(Subsection('A subsection')):
            doc.append('Also some crazy characters: $&#{}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Basic document
    doc = Document('basic')
    fill_document(doc)

    doc.generate_pdf(clean_tex=False)
    doc.generate_tex()

    # Document with `\maketitle` command activated
    doc = Document()

    doc.preamble.append(Command('title', 'Awesome Title'))
    doc.preamble.append(Command('author', 'Anonymous author'))
    doc.preamble.append(Command('date', NoEscape(r'\today')))
    doc.append(NoEscape(r'\maketitle'))

    fill_document(doc)

    doc.generate_pdf('basic_maketitle', clean_tex=False)

    # Add stuff to the document
    with doc.create(Section('A second section')):
        doc.append('Some text.')

    doc.generate_pdf('basic_maketitle2', clean_tex=False)
    tex = doc.dumps()  # The document as string in LaTeX syntax
```

**Arquivo gerado:**

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
%
\title{Awesome Title}%
\author{Anonymous author}%
\date{\today}%
%
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
\maketitle%
\section{A section}%
Some regular text and some %
\textit{italic text. }%
\subsection{A subsection}%
Also some crazy characters: \$\&\#\{\}

%
\section{A second section}%
Some text.

%
\end{document}
```

**Tex compilado (basic_maketitle2.pdf):**

[image: PDF gerado]