# Integrando programas de cálculo matemático com arquivos TeX

Tags: latex, mathematica

Costumo trabalhar com o software chamado `Wolfram Mathematica`. Com este software eu executo cálculos matemáticos e obtenho seus resultados.

Uso também aplicativos que compilam arquivos TeX, mas que são somente para gerar relatórios em PDF (não executam os cálculos matemáticos).

No programa que executa os cálculos eu simplesmente converto o que desejo na linguagem TeX e colo no outro arquivo previamente configurado.

Normalmente faço o seguinte:

`Botão direito do mouse -> Copy As -> LaTeX`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aí colo no outro programa

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216050/integra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-latex-e-python) tentei buscar alguma informação

Por enquanto gostaria de alguns comentários se é possível obter uma solução através da linguagem que conhecerem. Estou apenas esperando comentários porque sei que é de costume postar alguma tentativa, mas ficarei devendo.

Comment: O LaTeX tem inclusão de arquivos verbatim, aí você poderia fazer o Mathematica direcionar a saída para o "formula_1.tex" e incluir no arquivo principal essa saída

Comment: Vou testar. Acho que entendi. valeu

Comment: Se o teste der certo, posta uma resposta aqui do como funcionou